# Why doesn't the CORS problem occur on the backend server?

Tags: api, express, vue.js, cors

I am studying on a toy project using Vue. During development, I made api requests using axios from the front-end and faced a CORS problem. I would really appreciate it if you could give me some information.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '...' from origin 'http://localhost:8080'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
>   pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource.

I know CORS issues are caused by security issues when the requested domain and the responding domain are different. Is that so?

Anyway, I saw the information to enter "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" in the request header, but it didn't work.

So I searched for more information. As a result, I created an express server and configured the proxy for the vue project as shown below.

```
//vue.config.js
module.exports = {

outputDir:"backend/public",
assetsDir:"assets",
configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map'
},
devServer: {
    proxy: {
        '/api': {
            target: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
            changeOrigin: true,
            pathRewrite: {
                '^/api': ''
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

And I just applied the basic example code provided by the api site to the default express environment.

The only thing that changed

1. Not requested from front-end. (A request was made at back-end (express).)
2. I used the request module, not axios.

**Why doesn't a CORS error occur when I make an api request on back-end (express)?**

Comment: Cors is a concept of Browsers not http in general, so it only strikes there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), CORS is a mechanism to add security to requests and data transfers between cross-origin **browsers** and servers, so it won't affect by back-end and proxy servers.

> Modern browsers use CORS in APIs such as XMLHttpRequest or Fetch to
>   mitigate the risks of cross-origin HTTP requests.